# Determining Date Paid by User for Specific Month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried to find something like this out there and I just couldn't find a similar question. Please let me know if I am asking something redundant here.

I have a google sheets workbook for tracking the contributions from club members for an investment club. The bank_transactions worksheet looks like this:

| Date | Money In | Money Out | Contribution Month | Reference Name | Account Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/10/2021 | 200 | 0 | May | Homer Simpson | 200 |
| 05/10/2021 | 200 | 0 | June | Homer Simpson | 400 |
| 05/12/2021 | 200 | 0 | May | Sideshow Bob | 600 |
| 05/13/2021 | 200 | 0 | May | Ned Flanders | 800 |
| 05/16/2021 | 200 | 0 | May | Moe Szyslak | 1000 |
| 05/20/2021 | 200 | 0 | June | Sideshow bob | 1200 |

I have another table where I want to reference when a member paid that month's dues. I want it to look like this:

|  | May | Jun | Jul |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Homer Simpson |  |  |  |
| Sideshow Bob |  |  |  |
| Ned Flanders |  |  |  |
| Moe Szyslak |  |  |  |

I want to populate the second table with data from the first and have tried the following but it just errors out:

```
=IF(B1=bank_transactions!$E$1:$E,IF(bank_transactions!$E$2:E,bank_transactions!$A$2:$A,0),0)
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Maybe the nested if statements doesn't work. Maybe it isn't running a loop like I was hoping. Not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you wana populate it with `Money In` column?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:F, "select E,sum(B) where E is not null group by E pivot D")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this help! I didn't even know about the query function. I really appreciate your help. I was trying to pull in the date they paid for that month so I made a slight modification and apparently because I am not using an agg function, I cannot do the pivot.

So this is where I am now:
 `=QUERY($A$2:$F,"select E, A where B > 0 PIVOT D")`

Comment: @MattyIse https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u7w3FDY8P_M4qw9Jt_wxPhHzZxJpuO6BxL4Cb9RzuuU/edit#gid=0